# XCode Allocations Instrument not showing all CGImage allocations

Tags: xcode, memory-management, instruments, cgimage

When I'm debugging my OSX application using the Allocations instrument, I've found a memory buildup over time of CGImages (not the issue in question).

Looking at the Allocation Summary pane of the Allocations tool, for this certain timeframe, I have 32 CGImages in persistent memory. But when I zoom in the scope to show me all the allocations of CGImage, it only shows 4 allocations.

Allocation Summary: 
[Allocation Summary Pane, Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/od3Kk.png)

Zoomed scope for allocations of CGImage:
[Allocation list for CGImage only, Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVCxK.png)

In every other class I can actually see all of the individual allocations, but for some reason I cannot see all the allocations for CGImage (the same problem exists with CG raster data, which I assume is correlated to CGImage). Is this a bug in Allocations (probably not) or something that I'm just missing?